# How to set value foreign key of foreign key Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

> Visit Model

```
        id
        user_id
        visit_date
        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(USER::class,'user_id','user_id')->withTrashed();
        }
```

> ```
> User Model
> ```

```
user_id
branch_id
name
  public function branch()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(BRANCH::class,'branch_id','branch_id')->withTrashed();
    }
```

> Branch Model

```
branch_id
branch_desc
```

`I want to display branch_desc when getting list of Visit.`
Currently Im showing only branch_id from User Model

Comment: for 2 layers (or more) relationships, I recommend you install this package https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep and check tutorial related to it from LaravelDaily https://youtu.be/wgdWokrm3Mw

Comment: `SOLVED!!!`

    Use this in getting list of your model in Controller. This is how to query with multiple relationship
    
    $visit= VISIT::with('USER.BRANCH')->orderBy('user_id','desc');

Answer (score 0):

You need to make one to Many relation from visit to user table and user to branch table

ex. of relationship code:

```
//From Visit to User model
$this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id')

//From User to Branch Model
$this-belongsTo(Branch::clas, 'branch_id')
```

This will allow you to eager load the relationships in you controller like this

```
Visit::with(['user.branch'])
//Now you will get all visits with neseted users and branch
```

I will recommend you to take a look at laravel relationships docs for a better understanding
[Laravel Relationships with eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: `SOLVED!!!`

    Use this in getting list of your model in Controller. This is how to query with multiple relationship
    
    $visit= VISIT::with('USER.BRANCH')->orderBy('user_id','desc');

Answer (score 0):

For 2 layers (or more) relationships, I recommend you install this package from Staudenmeir https://github.com/staudenmeir/eloquent-has-many-deep

Inside your Visit model, you can add the relationship like this:

```
public function branches() {
  $query-> hasManyThrough(Branch::class, User::class);
}
```

And for more information , check LaravelDaily tutorial related to this package https://youtu.be/wgdWokrm3Mw

Comment: `SOLVED!!!`

    Use this in getting list of your model in Controller. This is how to query with multiple relationship
    
    $visit= VISIT::with('USER.BRANCH')->orderBy('user_id','desc');

Comment: @ThinkerBell what is this 'USER.BRANCH' ? is it a const variable ? and is VISIT a const variable as well ?

Comment: USER BRANCH and VISIT were models sir

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't clear really! However from what I understand from your question you should also have a Branch model and migration.

So, from visit table you will fetch the users by the relation with user in your visit model.

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'id', 'user_id');
}
```

Then when you can fetch your user branches from your User model by your users relation with Branch.

```
public function branch()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Branch::class, 'user_id', 'id');
}
```

So, you will fetch data like this:

```
$visit->user->branch->description
```

You can replace description with any column_name_that_wish_to_fetch.

Answer (score 0):

If figured it out.

Use this in getting list of your model in Controller.
This is how to query with multiple relationship

```
$visit= VISIT::with('USER.BRANCH')->orderBy('user_id','desc');
```

Comment: You can checked your own answer ^_^